# Form submitHandler not working using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below is my form and jquery/ajax script for submitting my data. The issue I have is the "submitHandler" is not working. All the validation works by displaying error message to the user but no data gets posted. I am not seeing any errors in the console. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong.

The Form:

```
<form  method="" action=""  name="Form1" id="Form1" autocomplete="off" >
// all the form fields
</form>
```

The script:

```
$("#Form1").validate({
rules: {
    board: {
        required: true,
    },
    PromotionName: {
        required: true,
    },          
    FromDate: {
        required: true,
    },
    FromTimeH: {
        required: true,
    },
    FromTimeM: {
        required: true,
    },
    ToDate: {
        required: true,
    },
    ToTimeH: {
        required: true,
    },
    ToTimeM: {
        required: true,
    },
},
messages: {
    board: {
            required: "Please select a display board",
        },
    PromotionName: {
        required: "Please enter the promotional name",
    },          
    FromDate: {
        required: "Please select the start date",
    },
    FromTimeH: {
        required: "Please select the start time hours",
    },
    FromTimeM: {
        required: "Please select the start time mins",
    },
    ToDate: {
        required: "Please select the finish date",
    },
    ToTimeH: {
        required: "Please select the finish time hours",
    },
    ToTimeM: {
        required: "Please select the finish time mins",
    },
}, 
submitHandler: function(form) {  
  var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("Form1"));
  $.ajax({
      url: "insert_new_promotion.php",
      data: form_data,
      processData: false, 
      contentType: false, 
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data,status){ 
          alert(data);
      }
  }).done(function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
      window.location.reload();
  });
  return false;
}
});
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. I forgot to include "$(document).ready".